# Is there anyway to dynamically add a child to a JSX element?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to add a child to an existing JSX element (Let's call it *parent*).

I tried something like:

```
React.cloneElement( parent, props, child );
```

But that simply replaces the existing children with the new child, while I need the new child to be **added** to the existing children as a sibling.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
let children = React.Children.toArray(parent);
children.push(child);
React.cloneElement( parent, {...props, children: children } );
```

Comment: This makes the parent become the sibling as well

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing the adding dynamically (meaning, X-action would trigger Y-adding of elements), you can do this inside the render Life Cycle.

```
render() {
    return (
        <SomeParentComponent>
            {this.getNewElement()}
        </SomeParentComponent>
    );
}

getNewElement = _ => {
    return (<SomeComponent></SomeComponent>);
}
```

Comment: But what if I don't have (or don't want to have) access to the code of the parent JSX?